# AMP HTML google anlaytics custom page path

Tags: amp-html

on mobile web we do the following:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': '/Path/Path-URI-FROM-DESKTOP-Story-518333'});
```

to produce the exact same pageview on google analytics as we do it on our desktop websites.

anyone has a clue on how to set the parameter using amp?
we use the same UA for mobile,desktop and AMP and want summarized numbers.

(each variation has a slightly different URL - all have canonicals and so on)

Comment: Have you checked this out https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/analytics-vars.md#ampdocurl?

Answer (score 1):

you can't use the ga script, it is forbiden.
But zu can use json with the paramter that amp give you. 
See [analytics variable and sample](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/analytics-vars.md)